# how can I define how long a client was visiting a site

Tags: php

I have a site and I want to measure how long a client was connected to my site, one hour or two hour... or?  how is it possible? 
can someone help me in this regard.
it will be appreciated.

Comment: somebody told me it is possible by checking the cookies, but I don't know how?

Comment: This can be done with the help of JavaScript. PHP cannot do such a thing.

Comment: Google analytics already do this. _Why reinvent a wheel you can already use for free_ PS: Its not an exact science

Comment: first you'd have to define what 'visiting a site' means. Does having one page open and reading for 3 hours count as visiting for 3 hours? Then you'll need javascript. All other can be done with php (Sessions f.e.) and some storage.

Comment: As above, use an apropriate analytics software, Google Analytics, Kiss Metrics, Piwik

Comment: It can only be done by client side language like jquery, angular etc. If you just want analytic report then Google analytics is the best solution for you. it gives you every things even custom tracking of the data.

Comment: (you can output hidden iframe and go without javascript, just cookies+php+meta-http-refresh) but it's a strange solution, really, though it can help if someone disabled js for some reasons

Comment: Log the event when they first load, log the exit, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it's best to use analytic software but if you are looking for something simple (or just learning experience)

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionId'])) // No session, first time (subject to session timeout)
{
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO visitor_sessions(`started_on`, `last_checkin`) (" . time() . ", " . time() .")");
$_SESSION['sessionId'] = mysqli_insert_id();    // start the 'visiting session'
 }
else
{
    mysqli_query("UPDATE  visitor set `last_checkin` = " . time() . " WHERE id = " .$_SESSION['sessionId']); // Update last checkin
}

?>
```

visitor_sessions is a table with 3 columns, id, started_on and last_checkin (timestamps).

You can include this script in your pages thus updating last check_in with each new page opened or have jquery call it every x seconds to maintain time even if they just view a page.

PS: Code was not tested but this is the general idea